# Launching RoR server for an existing app gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

I just made my first setup of RoR, and creating a new application works fine. But when I want to run the rails server I get the following error:

C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/yaml_ext.rb:30:in 'remove_method': method 'to_yaml' not defined in Class (NameError)

I ran the "bundle install" in the app directory and installed all the necessary files (with some problems however, but I excluded the gems with problems in the gemfile) and the last bundle install said that I have successfully installed all the needed packs.

I'm lost and I can't find a similar error on the internet. Can you help me?

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that I'm not having a problem with a new application. It's running an existing one (that I didn't build, but works fine for others) that the error is related to. Here's the gemfile for that app:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.3'

gem 'mysql'

gem "haml", ">= 3.0.0"
gem "haml-rails"
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'delayed_job'
#gem 'auto_crawlers'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.beta'

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'mocha'
end
group :development do
  #gem "nifty-generators", "0.4.3", :git => "git://github.com/JonasNielsen/nifty-generators.git"
  gem 'fastercsv'

end
gem "mocha", :group => :test
```

Do you think the error is because I left out the two gems with "#" ? Those were causing problems at first, and I don't think I need them to test some minor changes in the app (some views that I have to modify)

Comment: Looks like you've included delayed_job as one of your gems and it seems to be giving you problems. Can you post your gemfile?

Comment: Your problem might be that you needed to bundle those other gems. Since they had problems, I'm betting you need to get those gems built first.

Comment: I added more details in my question. Doesn't running bundle install also build the gems? I'm new to this, sorry :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is being described, and supposedly fixed here: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issuesearch?state=open&q=yaml#issue/194

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the command line: `irb -rubygems -r delayed_job` and then from your bundled directory `bundle-exec irb -rubygems -r delayed_job` which will show if there is a difference between your system gems and your bundled setup - you might see an error in one or both attempts to run IRB.

If there is an error using bundle-exec but not with your system gems then it's a bundler issue. If not, are you sure the app is designed to function under Ruby 1.9? It looks like to_yaml isn't available at the point DJ is required, which implies it probably needs a `require "yaml"` somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried what you said (what I figured out of it, at least) but the first command just displayed another command line inside irb, and I'm lost there, don't know what to type. The second command was not understood, but I tried bundle -exec (with a space) and it still didn't work (unknown switches -exec -rubygems -r). I think I'm giving up and I'll wait until I meet with the guy that developed the app gives me more indications... Oh and to mention I'm using RoR on Windows!

Comment: sorry - irb is basically the same as script/console in rails - I was suggesting it might show or not show an error and help you find out what the problem is. If I were you I'd speak to the guy and see if it's designed for Ruby 1.9 - bet that's the problem.