# Exception NameError, LoadError thrown while starting rails app using unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

We are getting NameError, LoadError issues while *starting* our rails applications using unicorn (e.g. unicorn -p 3000). This started happening all of a sudden, how do I avoid this issue.

http://pastie.org/7146907

Comment: Can you paste the stacktrace from the logfile?

Comment: http://pastie.org/7146907

Comment: I can't really help here, but it seems like the same issue like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901282/launching-ror-server-for-an-existing-app-gives-error (delayedjob problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you run `bundle install` first? You should also start unicorn using `bundle exec unicorn ...`.